# How do you set the badge position with reCAPTCHA v3?

Tags: recaptcha

I would like to use an inline badge with v3, but there is no documentation on badge position for v3.

Comment: You mean [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible)? Find `data-badge` on page.

Comment: @kabanus I'm talking about https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3, that's the v2 doc.

Comment: Ahh I see. Looks iike they simply didn't write the docs yet - consider using their [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha) group to ask, I'm guessing a DEV could help you more easily.

Answer (score 54):

You can make the badge inline in V3 with just Javascript it's just not documented yet.

Set your `render` parameter to `explicit` and add a `onload` parameter for the callback, `onRecaptchaLoadCallback` for example.

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=onRecaptchaLoadCallback"></script>
```

Then set up your callback like so and don't forget to enter the id/DOM node of where you want your badge to go, in this case, the id is `inline-badge`.

```html
<script>
    function onRecaptchaLoadCallback() {
        var clientId = grecaptcha.render('inline-badge', {
            'sitekey': '6Ldqyn4UAAAAAN37vF4e1vsebmNYIA9UVXZ_RfSp',
            'badge': 'inline',
            'size': 'invisible'
        });

        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute(clientId, {
                    action: 'action_name'
                })
                .then(function(token) {
                    // Verify the token on the server.
                });
        });
    }
</script>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/thatguysam/g7juvkdb/)

[Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/recaptcha/gcIxsA2T3yA/Q_7ZDVueFQAJ)

Note:
Valid values for `'badge'` are `'inline'`, `'bottomleft'`, `'bottomright'`, and `'bottom'`.
`'bottom'` and `'bottomright'` are synonyms.

Comment: Now documented (to an extent) [in the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-customize-the-recaptcha-widget-or-badge) and [in the docs for the JS API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#js_api).

Comment: Without the need for a custom callback, just include the JavaScript like so: `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?badge=bottomleft"></script>` (kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68925399/1717535) on another thread.)

Comment: Note that to use `'badge': 'inline'` you MUST use `'size': 'invisible'`. But honestly, inline is so ugly because of its size and color that you're better off sticking with the default fixed design.

Answer (score 22):

I just have changed the CSS for the grecaptcha-badge class like this:

```
.grecaptcha-badge { 
    bottom:25px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 22):

**you can include this into your sass or css to align at left and keep the hover feature active.**

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
  width: 70px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease !important;
  left: 4px !important;
}

.grecaptcha-badge:hover {
  width: 256px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT1:** See the answer using the `render=explicit` parameters. This answer still works but it was before this feature was documented and not as clean.

---

I've managed to do just that by placing a relative box and detaching the reCaptcha v3 badge into it. Then some style adjustments are made to the container.

```css
#grecaptcha-box {
    width: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
}
#grecaptcha-box .grecaptcha-badge {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Then you place the box followed by your JavaScript.

```html
<form>
    <!-- Rest of your form here... -->
    <input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-token"  name="recaptcha-token">
    <input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-action" name="recaptcha-action">
</form>

<div id="grecaptcha-box"></div>

<!-- Recaptcha v3 -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
<script id="js-recaptcha-init">
const RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    // Remove badge from fixed place
    var gb = document.getElementsByClassName("grecaptcha-badge")[0];
    gb.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById('grecaptcha-box').appendChild(gb.cloneNode(true));

    gb.parentNode.removeChild(gb);

    // Do the normal recaptcha things...
    var grecaptcha_opts = {'action' : 'custom_action'};
    grecaptcha.execute(RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY, grecaptcha_opts)
        .then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById('recaptcha-token').value = token;
            document.getElementById('recaptcha-action').value = grecaptcha_opts.action;
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

After execute, you can move the badge by Javascript. It will fix recaptcha timeout error in firefox and chrome browsers.

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {  
        grecaptcha.execute('sitekey', {actienter code hereon: 'loginpage'}).then(function(token) {
               /* Move Google Badge to your Div ID */
               jQuery('.grecaptcha-badge').appendTo("#g-badge-newlocation");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Simple and just works.

Answer (score 2):

Just set it at the div section

```
<div vc-recaptcha
badge="bottomleft"
>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you set this? What's the vc-recaptcha-badge attribute?

Answer (score -1):

**HMTL EXAMPLE**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {       
    // ...
    jQuery('.grecaptcha-badge').appendTo('#recaptcha-container');
    jQuery('.grecaptcha-badge').removeAttr('style');
    // ...
});
```

```html
<form>
      <!-- others inputs-->
      <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
 </form>
```