# google reCAPTCHA v3 bottomleft

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Reading through the code at https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1531759913576/recaptcha__en.js there are numerous references to `bottomleft` (as opposed to `bottomright` where the icon is generally placed, I presume).

But how do I enable this setting and move the icon to the bottom left?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just worked this out. You need:

```js
window._grecaptcha_callback = () => {
  window.grecaptcha.render({
    sitekey: grecaptcha_key,
    badge: 'bottomleft',
  })
  window.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
    // grecaptcha is ready
  })
}
```

Then load the script as `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=_grecaptcha_callback`.

With this the way you call execute has to change slightly to simply

```
window.grecaptcha.execute(0, {action})
```

eg. `0` instead of the site key as the first argument.

Looking through the code there are a number of other undocumented settings:

```
sitekey, type, theme, size, tabindex, stoken, bind, preload, badge, s, pool, 'content-binding', action
```

But apart fromt `sitekey` and `badge` I don't know what they do. But they probably correspond roughly to the [settings for v2](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible).

Answer (score 12):

If you're using V3 Programatically you can instead alter your script to include the position.

Here's an example:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=YOURKEY&badge=bottomleft"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why they haven't documented this

Comment: This also works with the default include method: `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?badge=bottomleft"></script>`

Comment: Note that even though this works in a simple flow, it may not work using a caching plugin :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate the bottom left position and hover effect on the icon.

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
    right: auto !important;
    left: 0;
    width: 70px !important;

    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;

    &:hover {
        width: 256px !important;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe things have changed in the last 2 years, but you can just add `data-badge="bottomleft"` as an attribute in your submit button (or whatever element you have with the `g-recaptcha` class).

It also takes `data-theme="dark"` too, which is cool.

Still, I had to search the source code for `data-` to see what was available. It seems like the documentation for reCaptcha v3 is full of holes.

Answer (score 1):

This will put the badge in the bottom left and reduce his width cutting away the slide animation effect.

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
  width: 70px !important;
  left: 4px;
}
```